# Network namespace is not visible in shell script during system boot,

Tags: networking, namespaces

My requirement is to create new network namespace and start new process in that new network namespace during Ceontos boot. I'm doing the following.

In /etc/rc3.d/ i'm having 2 script files

- S91CreateNetworkNS - Here I'm creating the network namespace (say tmpns)
- S92StartProcess - Here I'm starting the new process in the created network namespace.

I facing the following issue

- In S91CreareNetworkNS script i'm using "ip netns add tmpns" to create the network namespace and after this command if I use "ip netns list" it is not listing the created network namespace "tmp".
- In 92StartProcess script my process is not starting (ip netns exec tmpns ) saying it is not able to find the network namespace "tmpns"
- But after system boot the network namespace is visible if i use the same command "ip nets list" in the command line.

Any suggestion will be really appreciable.

Comment: Since netns is created in /var/run/netns directory and is mounted on tmpfs. So need to know in which runlevel /var/run will be mounted so that creation of network namespace during system boot will solves the issue. Otherwise any alternate way for creating /var/run/netns directory during system bootup also helps to do this one